# Why does Poirot throw a shoulder into the man at the door at the nightclub?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-on-the-nile-2022

At the conclusion of *Death on the Nile* (2022), Hercule Poirot visits the jazz singer he is smitten with.

As he approaches her nightclub, he leads with a stiff shoulder into the man standing at the door.  This man is presumably the manager.

Was there something in the dialogue earlier that would explain why he did this?

Comment: I don't think it has any significance, it's just that they bump into each other since they are both not quite looking where they are going - Poirot is keeping his head low, trying to stay incognito, while the other man (who looks like a journalist) is starting to leave while writing something in his notepad. (I don't think the man at the door is the manager, but rather, a journalist - it looks like he is carrying a press camera in his bag.)

Comment: Do directors frequently put a scene into a movie that has no significance?  Not in ones that sell thousands and millions of dollars, and that have A-list celebrities acting in them.  I cannot accept that this is a throwaway scene.

Comment: It's not a throwaway scene, its purpose is to highlight that Poirot is trying to conceal his identity, or at least avoid notice (so in that sense, it's of significance that the other person is a journalist). It's a small window into Poirot's mind. It's just that I don't think the interaction has any deeper meaning than that. It's simply one of those little details that makes the world of the movie feel more fleshed out. Directors include such scenes frequently enough - the competent ones, at least (sure, there's a balance to be found there: Chekhov's gun and all that).

Comment: In addition to highlighting that Poirot is focused on concealing his identity, the scene adds a funny element